# question about Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

‎A subset A of a topological space ‎$ ‎(X, ‎\tau)‎‎‎$‎‎ has ‎$  ‎\gamma‎$‎-property if every open cover ‎‎$\{‎U‎_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in ‎I‎}$‎‎‎‎ of $‎cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎(A)‎‎$‎‎‎ there is finite ‎$‎I‎_0 ‎\subset ‎‎I‎$‎‎‎so that ‎‎$‎A‎  ‎\subseteq ‎\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in ‎I‎_0}   ‎cl‎ ‎_{‎\tau‎_{‎_{‎A‎}‎}‎‎} ‎(‎ ‎U‎_{\alpha} ‎\cap ‎A‎‎‎)‎  $.‎‎‎

Is a subset with a ‎$  ‎\gamma‎$‎-property in a Hausdorff space, closed?

Comment: Why should it be?

Answer (score 2):

No. Every non-closed subset whose closure is compact (such as $(0,1)$ inside $\mathbb{R}$) satisfies this property.